# IIS SMTP: connection open, but no 220 response

Tags: email, iis, smtp

I'm trying to send an email to my IIS (6) SMTP service.

The domain `mycustomer.myserver.com`is added to the domains list of the SMTP service. Port 25 is open, I can telnet there.

`telnet mycustomer.myserver.com 25`, gives no errors, but no message either. (other mail servers do show 220).

SMTPDIAG confirms this: `Error: Expected "220". Server is not accepting connections.
Failed to submit mail to mycustomer.myserver.com.`

Do I need any further configuration of my IIS SMTP to get this to work?
At this point, I do not have MX records, but I don't think that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found it:

Allowed connections were restricted to localhost, as configured under Access > Connection control.